# How to recreate a sentence by using unique words and order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been looking for how to write a program which will recreate a sentence with its order and individual words.

The individual words are stored in a file in this format:

```
i am what so deal with it
```

and the order is also in a separate file like so:

```
1 2 3 1 2 4 5 6 7
```

finally it should make the sentence:

```
>>>i am what i am so deal with it
```

sorry but I am unable to put a code that  tried because i am unable to find how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it.

```
In [4]: order = "1 2 3 1 2 4 5 6 7"

In [5]: words = "i am what so deal with it"

In [6]: word_list = words.split()

In [7]: word_list
Out[7]: ['i', 'am', 'what', 'so', 'deal', 'with', 'it']

In [8]: order = map(lambda x: int(x)-1, order.split())

In [9]: order
Out[9]: [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]

In [10]: " ".join([word_list[i] for i in order])
Out[10]: 'i am what i am so deal with it'
```

I subtract 1 in `In [8]: order = map(lambda x: int(x)-1, order.split())` because lists in python are indexed from 0. The code above uses builtins (`int`, `join`, `map` and `split`) so refer to Python documentation to understand what exactly they do.

Comment: thanks for adding an explantion about that are really helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

An often useful mitigation of mismatch in indexing is to prepend a 0 indexed dummy entry in the word base (in python code), so that the 1 based indexing from the select indices file used to build the sentence is directly used to construct the sentence sequence upon read of the indices file.

Thus I suggest to try:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function

word_base = None
with open('so_word_base.txt', 'rt') as f_base:
    word_base = [None] + [z.strip() for z in f_base.read().split()]

sentence_seq = None
with open('so_select_indices.txt', 'rt') as f_select:
    sentence_seq = [word_base[int(i)] for i in f_select.read().split()]

print(' '.join(sentence_seq))
```

with the file for the word "atoms" (so_word_base.txt):

```
i am what so deal with it
```

and the file for selecting the indices into that word "base" (so_select_indices.txt):

```
1 2 3 1 2 4 5 6 7
```

This yields:

```
i am what i am so deal with it
```

Note this is fragile like the other solutions suggested, which should be ok, so the OP learns how to implement such a minimal database like application ;-)

One might try to test for the `None` of the variables where it is explicitly set in more robust code, try to catch exceptions when files are not there or do not allow read or do not succeed in being parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Bit more "beginner friendly" solution:

```
words = open("words.txt",'r').read().split()
order = open("order.txt",'r').read().split()
result = ""
for i in order:
    result+= words[int(i)-1] + " "
print(result)
```

and the result is the same:

```
i am what i am so deal with it
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate to get the current position of the words, then create a dictionary. To read the files you can use something like this:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as f:
    string = f.read()

with open('file2.txt', 'r') as f:
    order = [int(i) for i in f.read().split()]
```

Then re-order the words:

```
string = "i am what so deal with it"
order = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]

string = string.split()

indexDict = {i:j for i,j in enumerate(string)}

newString = ' '.join([indexDict[i-1] for i in order])
```

Output:

```
>>> newString
'i am what i am so deal with it'
```